# Unity WebGL - working on localhost but not on server

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

i have a question about an WebGL exported unity project. Everything works like expected when I run the site on my local machine. After finish testing I uploaded the site on a server where apache is running. Unfortunately I got the following erros:

[image: error 1]

```
Uncaught (in promise) abort({}) at Error
    at jsStackTrace (blob:https://unity.my-site.com/d7a78aba-2b94-4a18-92ba-b81d44b2d226:943:12)
    at Object.stackTrace (blob:https://unity.my-site.com/d7a78aba-2b94-4a18-92ba-b81d44b2d226:957:11)
    at Object.onAbort (https://unity.my-site.com/js/unity/Build/UnityLoader.js:1139:50)
    at abort (blob:https://unity.my-site.com/d7a78aba-2b94-4a18-92ba-b81d44b2d226:26837:20)
    at blob:https://unity.my-site.com/d7a78aba-2b94-4a18-92ba-b81d44b2d226:1383:5
```

[image: error 2]

I guess there is something wrong with the apache configuration but I can't find anything about this. Cause I'm not that familiar with unity and webGl could someone give me an advice what to do here?

Comment: Did you copy all file files over?

Comment: Yes. I zipped the Build output and unzip it on the server. It has to be something on apaches side I think

Comment: seems weird as I use apache too, and dont suffer this.

Comment: Can you post your conf file maybe? Or do you have a .htaccess file in the Build folder or somewhere?

Comment: Or something is missing on the server side. Maybe this command would help me: apt list --installed

Comment: Neither .. its just a basic apache config.. Are you sure you copied up all the build sub folders? does this work on a very basic unity build? what version of unity are you using?

Comment: I know the problem. Cause I'm using a php framework where I embed the unity build. Unity makes some blob requests and those end up in 404 cause of the framework..

Comment: ah, more error trapping needed then

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a local web server setting or version issue... I currently use Wampserver 3.1.7 and Unity Unity v2020.2.7 games work fine in Chrome and Edge, but hang at the Unity progress load bar in Firefox. If I upload the same game code to my Go-daddy hosting account, it works fine in all browsers.

I know it's not a "fix" for the localhost/URL issue in Firefox but, for me, I know it will work when published.